# Solve IBVP of 1D nonlinear heat equation using matlab pdepe

Tags: partial-differential-equations, matlab, parabolic-pde

I'm wondering how to solve this 1D  PDE using Matlab `pdepe` function:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t}  = \partial_x \Big( D_0 \; (u\circ\theta)^{\alpha}\; \partial_x u \Big)$$

where $u(0,0) = 1,\; u(0,1) = 0, u(0,x) = u_0(x), x \in [0,1] $

the deviation is $\theta(x) = ax^{\beta} + b$

and $D_0, a, b, \alpha, \beta $ are constants.

I'm trying to "adjust" the pde to use Matlab `pdepe` function but I don't see how to choose the pde function to take into account the deviation since we must have a function of $(x,t,u,u_x)$.

Any idea to help?

Comment: This equation is in the wrong class for the solver you are trying to use. Consider that the special case of $u_t=0$ is a BVP for a DDE, not even a ODE.

Comment: Any suggestion or any other method to investigate?

Answer (score 1):

Separation of variables $u=X(x)T(t)$ yields
$$
X(x)\dot{T}(t) = D_0\, T(t)^{\alpha+1} \big( ( X\circ \theta )^\alpha X' \big)' (x) ,
$$
where the dot denotes differentiation w.r.t. time, and the prime denotes spatial differentiation.
Dividing by $X(x) T(t)^{\alpha+1}$ on both sides, a separation constant $\lambda$ is introduced so as to write differential equations for $X(x)$ and $T(t)$.
The differential equation
$$
\dot{T}(t) = -\lambda T(t)^{\alpha+1}
$$
satisfied by $T(t)$ is a [Bernoulli equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation), which can be solved analytically. The differential equation
$$
\big(X' (X\circ\theta)^\alpha \big)'(x) = -\lambda X(x)
$$
satisfied by $X(x)$ is more difficult to solve in general (it is a second-order nonlinear [delay differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delay_differential_equation)). However, it is possible to do so in some simpler particular cases -- consider for instance the case $\theta(x) = x$ where $(X^{1+\alpha})'' = -\lambda(1+\alpha) X$ may be addressed analytically. In the general case, one may rather use perturbation methods or numerical integration.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. 
In the case $\theta(x) = x$ there is no deviation, Matlab pdepe function can solve the pde numerically.